# change sampling rate in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

I have several laboratory data. all of them contain records of a way signal.
My way starts at 0 and end with 300 meters.

My Problem is, some timeries are measured with sampling rate of 1000 1/s and some with 10000 1/s.

I am looking for an elegant solution to change the 10000 1/s timeries to 1000 1/s.

My first Idea is to drop every tenth row. But maybe sbdy has a better idea?

Comment: check out [`DataFrame.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use this function : [DataFrame.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample).
This function is a useful method for frequency conversion.
Before use this function,you must set the time column to index,Good luck~